# Issue using Zclip in node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js, zclip

I am using Jquery's ZeroClip (jquery.zclip.min.js) to copy a text box's content to the system clipboard. I am working in node.js project. Here's my jquery code:

```
$("#invitationLinkcopy").click(function() {
  $("#invitationLinkcopy").zclip({
    path: "../../js/ZeroClipboard.swf",
    copy: function() {
      alert($("#invitationLink input").val());
      return $("#invitationLink input").val();
    }
  });
});
```

The rendered html piece of code is:

When i run it seems to run correctly and on the click of the button (id=invitationLinkcopy) it displays the content of the input text (#invitationLink input) in alert window. The problem is, it doesn't copy that content onto the clipboard. Please help where i could be wrong. Please note that i am working on my localhost.

Comment: Are you sure that the location of `path` is correct?

Comment: The rendered html is:

<a target="_blank" href="#" id="invitationLink"><input value="text to copy" style="width:100%" size=""></a>

Comment: It looks correct to me coz when i hover over the Copy button and right click, it displays the familiar flash player context menu also it correctly alerts the text contents.